# How to run e2image to backup a remote CentOS server?

Tags: filesystems, backup

Our server is hosted out of the country, I just have SSH access. I want to take an image backup of my server. I found the `e2image` utility to take an online backup of that server, but when I run `e2image -r /dev/sda1 sda1image`, the command does not run, instead it shows this error:

```
[root@server ~]# e2image -r /dev/sda1 image
e2image 1.39 (29-May-2006)
e2image: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Could any one help me, how I can take my whole server backup?

Comment: The error "Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1" indicates that /dev/sda1 is most likely not an ext2/3/4 filesystem.  Do you us LVM?  Is it some other filesystem, such as FAT, reiserfs, XFS, swap, etc.?  Maybe you should also post the contents of /proc/mounts ?

Comment: Better `/etc/mtab` than `/proc/mounts` since then the entry for `/` will be correct.

Comment: Perhaps rsync may be more appropriate. You'd probably want the options `-axHAX` to preserve everything about the filesystem. Or perhaps just `tar -zc / | ssh foo.bar "cat > output.tar.gz"`

Answer (score 3):

As Max said, you seem to be running `e2image` on a filesystem that is not ext[234].  More importantly, `e2image` is not a backup tool.  It only stores the fs metadata in the image file so that you can send it to a developer to debug what went wrong with a corrupted fs.  It explicitly leaves out your data.

Comment: in man e2image(8) it says that "normally e2image only includes fs metadata, not regular file data.  The -a option can be specified to include all data. This *will give an image that is suitable to use to clone the entire FS or for backup purposes*". So it is not entirely wrong to intent e2image for backup, yet of course the fs has to fit (i.e. be an ext2/3/4) :)

Comment: @humanityANDpeace, yes, I added that feature some time after posting this answer ( it's from 2012! ).

Comment: From where are you getting this information? The `e2image` man-page itself says that it is meant as a backup tool and recommends using it to back up your system weekly and on each boot.

Comment: @NateT, I added the ability to include the data ( the -a switch ) and use it as a backup tool after this answer was originally posted.  This question may have been what inspired me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @jsbilling, `e2image` is looking for an ext filesystem, while the one you are giving it most likely isn't.

According to what I'm reading online, `e2image` has a very hard time with LVM, if that's your case.

Comment: `e2image` does not know or care about LVM

Comment: @ **e2**image is short for "ext2/3/4 to image". If you are implying that the fs type does not matter to `e2image`, that is wrong. LVM needs more than just the contents the filesystem to work.